# You may think I am in constant conflict, you may think I am sharp

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> You may think I am in constant conflict,
>
> You may think I am sharp,
>
> But those are just in my name!
>
> I am surrounded by a synonym of pillar(s) or post(s).
>
> I am the main child (also the biggest) of my parent
>
> My first is capital, my parent's first is capital, and my whole is capital
>
> My parent was also involved in the starting point of something big and widespread (not pleasant though).
>
> **What Am I?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are

> WARSAW.

*You may think I am in constant conflict.*

> WAR ...

*You may think I am sharp.*

> ... SAW.

*But these things are just in my name!*

> Indeed.

*I am surrounded by a synonym of pillar(s) or post(s).*

> Poles.

*I am the main child (also the biggest) of my parent.*

> Capital and largest city of Poland.

*My first is capital, My parent's first is capital, and my whole is capital*

> The W of Warsaw, the P of Poland, and Warsaw itself are all capital.

*My parent was also involved in the starting point of something big and widespread (not pleasant though)*

> The Second World War (German invasion of Poland).

---

**Feedback section**

This was a fun riddle, and not too simple (it took me a minute or two to work out), but the *method* of solution was fairly obvious from the outset. After the first three lines I knew we were looking for a word which was homophonically a combination of something in constant conflict and something sharp. I was lucky enough that "sword" was my first guess for the latter, but "war" was a pretty clear guess for the former. Once found, the solution is very clearly self-confirming, which is good.

Comment: Nice! My first guess was crossword, and it almost fit but for the last line

Comment: @thecoder16 Curious: what would the "parent" be for crossword?

Comment: You got it @Randal'Thor, and I love the feedback :D (a green check is in your future)

Comment: Wow Rand... two minutes?

Comment: @Randal'Thor uh... puzzles? :P crossword puzzles are one of the most popular, seen in newspapers commonly. yeah... doesn't quite fit

Comment: `Not too simple (it took me a minute or two to work out)`. I LOL'ed.

Answer (score 5):

Is the answer

> QuantumTwinkie? The quantum realm is in constant conflict, and some people may think that @QuantumTwinkie is sharp. QuantumTwinkie is the OP's name, um, a twinkie looks like a pillar if you raise it upright! Maybe QuantumTwinkie is the firstborn or perhaps refers to the Big Bang... the parent of everything... or the creators of twinkies are super rich. Twinkie creators could've started a childhood obesity epidemic, and if its Quantum, then well, theres way too much stuff Quantum force can generate

Comment: Great answer but unfortunately not correct. +1 for creativity!

Comment: Haha, this answer is funny! :P @North

Comment: I got this idea from one of your riddles @MicCrozier

Comment: I figured that! :)